# How would primordial black hole forms if expansion of space overwhelms gravity?

Tags: black-holes, universe, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

I read that density is quite high in the early universe and many speculate that primordial black hole can form and would probably have a mass similar to a human ovum(egg cell). Usually black hole only forms during gravitational collapse of massive star, we know gravitational force is extremely weak and so there should be not enough time for matter or energy to gather into a tiny region of space and produce black hole. So what created these primordial black holes?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How likely are Primordial Black Holes to form in the early universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/400296/) though that question hasn't attracted any answers yet.

Comment: I've placed a bounty on the duplicate question in the hope that will prompt someone to answer. It's an interesting question since we have some idea of the inhomogeneity from the CMB spectrum.

Comment: @JohnRennie OK but I can't delete my question because the phone apps do not support this function, probably will have to wait till a pc is available

Comment: I wouldn't delete the question. Your question has now been linked to the other question so it is in effect acting as a signpost. Having duplicates makes searching for answers easier.